# FFMPEG and Powershell Script not working (worked in the past)

Tags: ffmpeg, script, video-conversion

I had to reinstall windows, now I'm trying to get it working again with no luck.

The Script is a .ts to .mp4 batch converter, when I set it up the first time, I included the link at the top for reference, but unless I'm blind, didn't see my solution there.

```
<# Change .ts to video format to change from
https://www.junian.net/tech/powershell-ffmpeg-batch/ #>

$originalVids = Get-ChildItem *.ts -Recurse

foreach ($inputVid in $originalVids) {
    $outputVid = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($inputVid.FullName, '.mp4')
    ffmpeg.exe -i $inputVid.FullName -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a aac -map_metadata 0 $outputVid
}
```

FFMPEG path is below, and is set in the Environment Variables, I checked it and it's working properly.

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin
```

I have VS Code set up to run it, and Powershell, I've tested both, and neither work. The error I get is below:

```
Invalid data found when processing input
```

I know I'm forgetting something simple, but for the life of me, I can't remember.

EDIT:

<s>Looking at the path before the error, I just realized OneDrive was enabled in the other configuration, but isn't now, and is in the file path. I am 99% sure this is the issue.</s>

---

My assumption in this edit is incorrect, I have OneDrive disabled, thinking it was taken out of the path, but it's still there. So the path is valid, I followed it all the way.

From other posts, I have gathered that my files might be incomplete, which I don't understand. But I'm trying to figure it out myself.

END EDIT.

Comment: Can you test it with different input files? Can you confirm that ffmpeg works correctly without using the script, e.g. by running `ffmpeg -i somefile.mkv -c:a copy -c:v copy outputfile.mkv`? Also please add the full error in appropriate code tags (`{}` button)

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect tags, I'm learning, but am pleased when I remember to put any tags around something.

But will do that now.

Also, it may not be the best fix, but I got it working, but thanks for your response.

Comment: Don't worry, you've used code tags for the script, which is perfect. Putting commands and output in code tags is also not "necessary" in this case, but gains importance with more special symbols used, as they could be parsed by the browser/webserver. It is also better for readability, thats why I've edited your post. Nice that you've found the answer by yourself and even nicer that you've posted if here, for the next one with a similar problem. By the way, welcome to superuser!

Comment: I've also put your edits in correct chronological order and crossed out your "wrong assumption" with `<s>crossed out text</s>`, again, just for readability, you did everything correct. One thing I might note again: Please add all the information your system is outputting and about the environment to the question, even if it seems not relevant to you at first. `Invalid data found when processing input` could have multiple causes, in this case it was a permissions problem, which could (possibly) only be found with the preceding lines of output.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I was getting a different error for Powershell and VS Code.

The error for PS was access denied, so I first created a new folder in the same folder, and transferred all of the ts files and the script into it, with no luck.

I then launched PS as admin, and copy/pasted the script manually in the elevated PS, and it worked.

Comment: You might still want to fix the permission error, as you (probably) shouldn't rely on admin permissions to access your media files. I assume you use an external drive used on different machines with different user names?